# Jekyll kramdown does not support reference links

Tags: markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I try using [kramdown reference links](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#reference-links) in Jekyll. Reference links do not work (Jekyll does not produce  tags). Inline links work as expected.

I simply copied the example from the [kramdown syntax reference](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#reference-links) into my Kramdown document.

```
This is a [reference style link][linkid] to a page. And [this]
[linkid] is also a link. As is [this][] and [THIS].
```

Please could one reproduce this issue or confirm, that it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the *reference* though..
For example:

```
This is a [reference style link][linkid] to a page. And [this]
[linkid] is also a link.


[linkid]: http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks, understand now. I misunderstood the meaning of reference links. Actually I  would like to link to generated HTML anchors. To ```# This is a heading``` I can link with ```[Linktext](#this-is-a-heading)```. Thought reference links are a kind of shortcut doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a footnote:

```
This is a text with a footnote[^1].

[^1]: And here is the definition.
```

https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#footnotes